# Gracenote does not seem to recoginize VOD content

Tags: gracenote

I've been trying to test gracenote over some VOD content, however It doesn't seem to recognize VOD content. Does Gracenote work with VOD content?

I always assume that it work with both live and VOD content. And I recall that it used recognize VOD content before (a few months ago), however no matter how I changes the settings and license, it cannot recognize VOD content at all.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your Gracenote contact. Your client id needs to be routed correctly to recognise VOD content. This is not something you can change by yourself.